# Есть ли инструмент дебагинга позволяющий исполнять код по строчно при отправке запроса на Django?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Чтобы можно было включить дебаг и зайти на страницу и открылось бы окно где можно было бы исполнять код по строчно. Для Фреймворка Django

Comment: pyCharm может ?

Comment: Запускаете django в консоли и юзаете pdb.

Comment: @Citizen, как работает django точно понимаете? Можно произвести только общую отладку, контрольные точки бесполезны, метки и логирование то что нужно. Если пропустить "магию", то в том же views, пока render не будет, в браузере ничего не увидим. Дополнения разработчика https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/developer-tools/

Comment: @Igor под pycharm всё прекрасно отлаживается. В том числе внутри самого django библиотечный код, в том числе (если очень приспичит) на удаленном сервере.